# PHP big array performance?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question regarding array's performance with huge amount of elements. I have this big array that currently has about 100 elements and I will keep adding to it in the future so it will get larger and larger with time. My question is, will there be a huge performance impact when this array gets to 500+ elements or more?

```
  $pages=array(
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>',
  '<div class="article"><img src="image url here"></div>');
  }
```

Comment: Only thing I can say is why save all the HTML in the array? I mean. [Class = "article"] and [src = {URL}] is all you actually have to Dave in the array?

Comment: yes. I'm creating a pagination in my website and the array would store the HTML which in this case it would be the divs and the img. It will be exactly like this but in PHP. So if this becomes with 1000+ elements, it won't impact the performance much? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GENGJW

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what a pagination is. All I'm saying is that I don't think there is any need to store multiple duplicate HTML divs in the array. It could probably be solved at output with a select case and output the HTML together with array details.

Comment: I'm not using a database.

Comment: not sure why that would matter. It's a simple select case or if() and your array will be significantly smaller. If I understand your code and array correct.

Comment: You said "I don't think there is any need to store multiple duplicate HTML divs in the array". They are not duplicate. Originally, I had them outside the array so I put them inside the array to achieve the pagination.

Comment: After googling what pagination is, I stand by my previous comment. You do not need to store the HTML in an array. HTML is static, the part that may be dynamic can easily be handled with if().

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve in PHP. How would I achieve this without putting the HTML in an array? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GENGJW

Comment: For example like this; https://3v4l.org/KGL6W . same HTML output but the array is significantly smaller. If all divs are "article" then you can delete that too from the array.

Comment: I see what you are saying but each element in the array will contain four divs: 1) a div with the title. 2) a div with an img. 3) a div with a description 4) a div with the date published, comment count. That's why I thought of putting each one as a seperate element rather than splitting it up like you mentioned. Sort of like this www.techpowerup.com/reviews/

Comment: You can do however you want I just wanted to shred some light on a different angle of this question you had. (Large arrays). One way is to find out if there is a limit, your way. One way is to make the array smaller so that any size limit is not a problem

Comment: Do you think the performance will be bad when the array gets large, say 10K? All the array will do is print the elements.

Comment: Don't know. I can only speculate. If the rest of the page is memory heavy... Maybe... As I said before I just wanted to shred some light on the topic. I have no proof in either direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500+ will not do HUGE impact on performance. If your server has good RAM you do not need to be worry even though it reaches like, 10,000 - 50,000+.

But your concern has a valid point regarding scale-ability. Try to index your array with a known key and always try to use `isset[<knonwn_key>]` other than going for `is_array` operation (as Joey stated).

Even after doing this if you face performance issues, it will be the time to go to `memcache`. (Going from normal array to memcache will be easy if you have a known key array)

Hope this would help you! Thanks.

Comment: I will be using the array to create a pagination. It will be exactly like this but in PHP. So if this becomes with 1000+ elements, it won't impact the performance much? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GENGJW

Comment: In a single page are you going to show 1000? OR is that all records and you are showing like 25 of them?

Comment: that is all the records and I will show 20 per page.

Comment: So performance wise, why bother about 1000? Get record count from back-end, calculate page count by `ceil(<all_count> / 20)`, LIMIT first 20 records (`LIMIT 0, 20`) and fetch their details. So your array always have only 20 (no performance issues at all). When you go to Page 2, calculate record count and page count, `LIMIT 20, 20`. Page 3, `LIMIT 40, 20` Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Defining an array with 500 items will probably go fast enough. If you're not doing anything interesting with the array other than printing out it's contents, you probably don't have to worry.

If you ever wondering something like this, just measure it.

Comment: I will be using the array to create a pagination. It will be exactly like this but in PHP https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GENGJW

Comment: Then yea you're fine, and in the future just measure. You can easily create some fake arrays with thousands of items and just see where it starts to get slow. Measuring is always better than asking.

Comment: whats the best way to properly measure this?

Comment: An easy way to get started with measuring: Call `microtime(true)` before your script and `microtime(true)` again after. If you subtract the first from the last, you know how long it took.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use various browser's developer tools to see how long it took for a HTTP response to arrive.

Comment: I created 12K fake elements in the array and the file size of the php page went up to 800KB. But honestly, I could not tell the difference between 12K items and 5 items.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there is no limit on the sizes of arrays. In your case, I don't see any major performance impact. The only thing you need to worry about is if it would cause a memory issue based on the memory allocated to your script (as you say your array would grow). This can be changed in the `'memory_limit'` in your php.ini configuration.

For a large array, performance also depends on the operations that you would perform once you have all the data in your large array. Operations like `in_array` would have to search the entire array in the worst case.

Comment: I will be using the array to create a pagination. It will be exactly like this but in PHP. So if this becomes with 1000+ elements, it won't impact the performance much? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GENGJW

Comment: Are you going to store the entire article or just an excerpt with a link?

Comment: just an excerpt with a link. The array will store all the excerpts and I will show 20 excerpts per page.

Comment: What about server side pagination (Ajax)? Then you really won't have to worry too much about performance or a really large array. If you want to see how this works, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807755/what-exactly-is-server-and-client-side-pagination

Comment: I'm not using a database.